# Solidity deployed in web3.py error: .call() function not working so I 'm not able to receive any data

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3py

I'm using ganache and vscode. I have a contract that I'm trying to deploy with a .py file using web3.py. It deploys, and transactions are working. But when I try to retrieve data with a view function, I get an error saying it's not synced. My project depends on retrieving data, please help me out!

```
print(funcs.showPDetails().call())  #Error causing line
#funcs is declared as contractname.functions & works with transactions
#showPDetails() is a view function in the contract with just a return line
```

Error (end of error messages):
web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?

Browsed the internet, a few people did have this issue but most were unanswered. One suggested solution to add time.sleep(50) did not make a difference for me.